# Ruby on Rails. The "view" mode display of the value is without trimming

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have following in the view.

```
<%= h @user.value %>
```

The "view" mode display of the value is trimming the leading (and I suppose trailing) spaces from the string. But I don't wont trim value.

[image]

Comment: What's the context, HTMLwise?  Most of the time whitespace in HTML doesn't matter, so whether or not it's included in the Ruby output may be irrelevant.

Comment: Why do you use `h` helper? In Rails 3 this is escaped by default.

Comment: Could you provide some clarification about what the normal output of `@user.value` is and the desired html output?

Comment: I have following string.

" Test "

The "view" mode display

"Test"

Answer (score 2):

HTML ignores the leading whitespace so you need to change spaces to `&nbsp;`. Something like this:

```
<%= @user.value.gsub(/ /, '&nbsp;').html_safe %>
```

Comment: That might cause the value to span over single line. Replacing only whitespace characters after `\A` (start of string) and only before `\z` (end of string) might give better results.

Comment: There is a potential security vulnerability with this if the `@user.value` comes from a user input

Answer (score 2):

How about a client side fix:

```
white-space: pre-wrap
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ph0ktovn/

[white-space docs](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp)